# Tell if a WordPress page has "grandchildren"

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, hierarchy

I want a conditional that checks if a page has at least 2 levels of children; that is, if its children have children. I know you can get ancestors, and get a page's depth, but I can't find a way to see if a page is a grandparent (or great-grandparent, etc.).
How can I construct a conditional statement that returns true if a page has more than one level of children?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if a post has a parent with `$post->post_parent`, if no parent returns 0.

```
if($post->post_parent == 0){
  // your code
}
```

The problem here is that i think you can`t check easily if a page has more than one.

You will need to create a custom query to get all pages that have a parent, put that result in an array, then use `array_count_values()` function to check for duplicates, now you can know if a page has more than one children....

I think you can do it that way

Comment: If I could find out how many levels are in the page's hierarchy, then see if the page is in the last or second-to-last level, I'd know it wasn't a grandparent (or higher). This seems conceivable, e.g. pagea>pageb>pagec>paged, pagea and pageb are grandparents/great-grandparents, but pagec and paged are not.